# Filter Kendo Dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-dropdown, dropdown

I have a kendo UI DropdownList that has values: 
User 1, User 2, User 3 and User 4 and I would like to hide User 1 and User 2 and only show User 3 and User 4 based on a certain condition. 
Here is the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO/10) for that. 
Kindly let me know how I can achieve the above.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to achieve this. See one of them here:

> http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO/16

I've moved the data from the html markup to a local JavaScript variable. Then a kendo DropDownList is being initialized (you didn't initialized it at all) with the WHOLE data. Then the data is being filtered via dropDownList's dataSource via its filter() method.

If your data comes from the server, you should send only the data which you need. By this approach the network traffic will be as minimum as possible and no additional filtering will be done on the client. This can be achived with additional settings in dataSource. Please take a deep look at kendo's documentation for [dataSource](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) and [dropDownList](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist).

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. The issue is that the control is already initialized server-side and I am just performing the filtering on the client side. Is there no way to perform the filtering without re-initializing the control all over again?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just use this snippet in JavaScript, upon document.ready or any other place, where you should do the filtration, and it should work.

`var ds = $('#users').data('kendoDropDownList').dataSource;
            ds.filter({
                logic: 'or',
                filters: [
                  { field: "value", operator: "eq", value: 3 },
                  { field: "value", operator: "eq", value: 4 }
                ]
            });`

Comment: It doesn't work with dropdownlist. Could you please amend your Dojo to match this.

Comment: The snippet I've provided is already in the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eyORO/16). Please show me how you initialize the widget server side.